# Run IntelliJ code formatter from the command line

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to run IntelliJ code formatter from command line.

I know that [inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections-offline.html?search=forma) can be run from CLI, however, they didn't provide the same for the source formatting (lame!).

Now, I started with CE edition of IntelliJ. Source code is on [github](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community).

However, since the code base is not small, I am having problems encapsulating the formatter.

Is there anyone who can point me in right direction and showing which classes to start with?

Comment: Hi Igor, have a look at how "UpSource" is built. It offers code based operations "outside" of the intellij product - so there must be "a way in" to the functions you need.

Comment: Didn't know that, nice! UpSource is not open-source, but hey, decompiler is my friend :)

Comment: Btw, @vikingsteve I am not able to find anything in the upsource docs about the formatting. Maybe YouTrack is better for that?

Comment: Perhaps. Or maybe if you can find the UpSource source code some place, you can find how it calls / utilizes the core "intellij.lang" libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the formatter from the terminal now. Like the code inspection.
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter

/bin/format.sh [-h] [-r|-R] [-s|-settings settingsPath] [-m|-mask masks] [path1 [path2]...]

On Windows it's /bin/format.bat

Comment: @vvondra, I would say yes.

Comment: ...because you can manually start a format job without using the format.sh script. `./idea.sh format -s /path/to/your/settings.xml /path/to/your/folder`. (I didn't want to create two comments. I'm new to stackoverflow and unintentionally added the first comment :( ).

Comment: I realized my mistake, it's only available from IDEA 2016.3

Answer (score 4):

To do this in the new versions of Intellij

You need to make sure the command line launcher is installed via the Jetbrain Toolbox.

[Toolbox App Announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/08/23/toolbox-app-1-11-whats-new/)

And run the following command from your shell:

```
idea format -s /path/to/your/style.xml /path/to/your/folder
```

I would recommend that you set the shell script location to **/usr/local/bin/**